# Windows DLL initialise array of constant c strings with file

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll

#### Background

I am currently working on a project for which I have written a DLL as an interface between a Windows driver and MATLAB. All of this is working very well, but one thing up until recently it has been lacking is documentation for certain functionality - essentially it allows command strings to be sent to an FPGA, and all of these commands need documenting.

This could be done using a PDF etc. but I wanted also a way to integrate it the documentation into the DLL itself - so functions like 'lookup command' etc. can be used. At any rate I went ahead and implemented this in a way which I am mostly satisfied.

Essentially I have a structure (see below) to which a pointer can be returned from functions so that the documentation can be accessed. The caller provides the address of a pointer to one of these which is then updated with the address of an entry in a constant global array.

```
typedef struct {
    CONST CHAR * commandString;
    ULONG commandStringLen;
    CONST CHAR * documentationString;
    ULONG documentationStringLen;
    CONST CHAR * commandParameters;
    ULONG commandParametersLen;
} COMMAND_DOCS;

#define STRING_LEN(a) a,(sizeof(a)-1)
#define NEWGROUP  "\n    "
#define NEWENTRY  "\n              "
#define NEWLINE   "\n"
#define ENDTITLE  "\n----------------------------------------\n"

CONST COMMAND_DOCS CommandDocs[] = {
//-----
#define COMMAND_xyz_GROUP_INDEX_START      (0)
        { STRING_LEN("ABCD"), 
          STRING_LEN("Something Command"
                     ENDTITLE"Low Queue"
                     NEWLINE "Description:"
                     NEWGROUP"The .........."
                     NEWLINE), 
          STRING_LEN(NEWGROUP"Type x:"
                     NEWENTRY"No Payload"
                     NEWLINE)
        },
#define COMMAND_xyz_GROUP_LENGTH           (1)
//-----
    ... And so on
};
```

This results in a load of constant strings being stored in memory and an array of documentation structures which contain pointers to these constants and their lengths as well for good measure. A pointer to the required element in the array is returned as I say. The caller of the library API is then free to make copies if needed or display the strings, whatever.

This is all working nicely at the moment, except for a minor annoyance. Whenever I need to update the documentation, it required me to recompile the DLL - as clearly all of the strings are compiled into it. For me that is not an issue as I can easily compile it, but as I am working at a university developing a research platform for them to use, I want it to be as simple for people to update in the future as I move on to other work. Ideally if documentation needs updating - say new commands get added to the system, I would like the additions to be possible without having to do a recompile.

---

#### Question

So my question really is about what the best way to go about doing this is.

At the moment I am thinking along the lines of loading the documentation from a file, either at the time of loading the DLL, or when the search function is called. Currently there are #defines in the array to separate indexes (identify groups of commands), but these could be replaced by variables that are initialised by data from the file.

I could go for something like XML and parse that to fill up the structures, but part of me thinks it would be easier to understand in the outside world if it was something simpler, but then I suppose I would still need some way of identifying the boundaries between entries, etc.

Thoughts?

---

Note that the DLL is mostly C - all of the APIs are C interfaces, but internally it is C++ as I've been using classes for other parts. I don't mind which is used as long as it is compatible with C interfaces.

Comment: You can include the docs as a resource in the DLL. Then it can be updated using only a resource linker. But the easiest is a separate file (or files). These techniques can be combined.

Comment: I personally would use an xml or json file. The advantage to this is that all the person needs to make changes to the documentation is a text editor. If you keep the file simple, it should be easy for anyone to work out how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went away from the problem for a while as it wasn't urgent, but have come back to it in the last few weeks. I've found that I need to add even more settings and configurable stuff to the DLL which makes the approach I was using before definitely not useable.

Basically as @PhilWilliams suggested in the comments, I've gone for using XML files for configuring everything. There are now some APIs that have to be called just after loading the library with which the location of the XML file to load is specified. The DLL will then parse the XML files and populate a load of internal structures. Rather than using #defines and constant strings, I now have an array of structs in which pointers to the parsed strings are located along with the indices which were previously #defines.

After looking on StackOverflow and finding various suggestions on simple XML parsers, I've gone for TinyXML2 as it means that I don't have the headache of allocating and freeing memory for the many documentation strings as it handles that internally.